# Paypal API for preapproved payments , is the merchant charged for pre-approved transactions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm running an classified ads website and I'm charging a specific fee for each ad placed. As you may know paypal charges a specific percent for each transaction + a specific amount fee (e.g 2,9% + 0.30 cents) 
. I have customers who place about 30 ads per month therefore I would like to integrate a schema that would cut the specific amount fee . Basically I'm looking to make "pre-approve" call every time after the client place an ad to make sure that he has the money to pay and at the end of the month to cancel all the scheduled pre-approved transactions and make a single payment request with the whole amount. The question that I have is : Will I be charged for the pre-approved transactions that I cancel ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer for the specifics of PP, but I would try to not go about it that way. Instead have clients pay in advance for a number of ads, at a suitable discount reflecting the fact that you're not paying the PP tax every time.

Comment: that would not be a good user experience

Comment: Fair enough; you know your users better than I do.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that paypal is charging a fee for pre-approval requests .